# Split content based on the attribute value in XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Is there any way to split the content as well as the attribute value using XSLT.

My input will look like:

```
 <element id=”value1, value2, value3”>value1; value2; value3</element>
```

and the required output is"

```
<a href=”#value1”>value1</a>; <a href=”#value2”>value2</a>; <a href=”#value3”>value3</a>
```

Help me the possible way to do this in XSLT.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<xsl:template match="element[@id]">
  <xsl:variable name="att-values" select="tokenize(@id, ', ')"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '; ')">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() gt 1"><xsl:text>; </xsl:text></xsl:if>
    <a href="#{$att-values[$pos]}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </a>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```